# Property 'pagingScrollView' not found on object of type 'PSPDFViewController *'

Tags: ios, objective-c, pspdfkit

In latest PSPDFKit (iOS) with Objective C,

"pagingScrollView" property not available to get pdfviewcontroller's Scrollview.

How I can get UIScrollview of PSPDFViewController ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documents](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/migration-guides/pspdfkit-70-migration-guide/) of PSPDFKit, when you migrated from 6v to 7v there is a lot of API breaks.

In 7 version of PSPDFKit:

> Directly accessing the scroll view is no longer supported. Implement
>   -`[PSPDFDocumentViewControllerDelegate documentViewController: configureScrollView:] or -[PSPDFDocumentViewControllerDelegate
>   documentViewController: configureZoomView: forSpreadAtIndex:]`
>   depending on your needs.

Comment: @user3522538 You're welcome, If my answer is correct please set green check market and give me an upvote, Thanks :)